# How to Group Documents by a Field and Calculate Count in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

How to write the below aggregation query in java.Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

My documents in mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d6b5849d6e45832c36482a"), "name" : "abc", "count" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d6b5899d6e45832c36482b"), "name" : "abc", "count" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d6b5949d6e45832c36482c"), "name" : "xyz", "count" : 50 }
```

My query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$name",total:{$sum:"$count"}}}
])
```

o/p:

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "total" : 300 }
{ "_id" : "xyz", "total" : 50 }
```

Comment: If you have tried then it would be nice to show us what you tried. Also "aggregation" and "updating" are two different things, so which is it you really want to do? You could be a lot more clear in what you are asking as well as making some sort of attempt. It's easier to advise you when you show what you try since it gives some idea of where you are going with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.getCollection("orders").aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$name").append("total", new Document("$sum", "$count")))));

Hopes this will help.